# System.ArgumentException/invalid parameter exception thrown despite empty code

Tags: c#, exception

I tried debugging in order to find the bug in question but I can't since the issue seems to be thrown deep in a routine used by System.Drawing *(`System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc` to be more precise)*

This is my class, which is located in another project within the same solution. This class is compiled as a library (dll), and that library is referenced by my example project, which is an executable.

```
namespace CTRGui
{
    public class CTRForm : Form
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, the class is COMPLETELY empty and only inherits from Form. The next code segment is my entrypoint in my example project. Reminder that CTRForm is part of a library referenced by my example project.

```
namespace CTRGuiExample
{
    class Example
    {
        static void Main(string[] Args)
        {
            CTRGui.CTRForm form = new CTRGui.CTRForm();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

The (visual) debugger shows that the exception was thrown on Application.Run (normal considering it doesn't have the PDB/source code), and the call stack tells me that the System.ArgumentException is actually thrown in `System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc`

Despite debugging, in vain, I wasn't able to find any fix to this issue.

**edit:** Exception details, as requested.

Copied exception details that VS gave me:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
  InnerException:
```

Exception info shown in Visual Studio:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

Call stack:

```
    System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc() Unknown
    System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.RenderInternal(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef refTargetDC, System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics buffer) Unknown
    System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.Render() Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown
>   CTRGuiExample.exe!CTRGuiExample.Example.Main(string[] Args) Line 15 C#
```

Comment: As the problem does not repro, please include all exception details in your questions so that we can get a clue what might be the problem here.

Comment: @DirkVollmar Added what I could find.

Comment: Does this problem occur on different machines and also still after a reboot? Any is the code shown really the only code in your application? The problem might be caused by a GDI leak. Open task manager and add the GDI objects column and have a look whether the value is high / increasing.

Comment: You are missing the `CTRForm.Designer.cs` and the `CTRForm.resx` files.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm This doesn't use the designer at all.

Comment: @DirkVollmar The problem persists between machines and between reboots. What I gave is the only code, and the GDI count is constant and low (31)/doesn't increase.

Comment: Are you using visual studio or a command line tool to build?

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm Visual Studio.

Comment: Try this on a freshly installed system with no other things installed. There seems to be something broken on the machines you tried this on. GDIplus errors under the hood are a bit difficult to analyse, as all we have is a status code of InvalidParameter (= 2) returned from a call to [`GdipGetDC`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,9aa931b146439086)